# Connecting to Bluemix from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, authentication, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to connect to Bluemix from Eclipse using this url : https://api.ng.bluemix.net

I entered my Bluemix id and password but it said wrong email or password. I do not know what was wrong since I was able to use both from my Bluemix console?

Comment: The same credentials work on the web site itself, https://ng.bluemix.net/ ?

Comment: The URL `https://api.ng.bluemix.net` is correct.  Make sure you do not have any network issues.  Can you try the CLI as well?

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you select the "Validate Account" button? I see the following message displayed when I try to validate:

[image: validateAccount button example]

Answer (score 0):

Did you have account on site:console.ng.bluemix.net?